# Are there any very Simple JQuery Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Hi I'm looking to add some simple validation to a form.

There are 2 textboxes which the user is expected to enter only numbers and it must be greater than zero.  The jquery code is in it's own file (the form consists of html / jquery / php).  The first number is for 'previous age' and the second number is for 'current age'.  For example, if the user enters '0' in either textbox, an alert or message box should appear informing them that they need to enter a number greater than zero. Anything other than a number greater than zero entered into the textbox should result in the alert message.

As a side note, the .php file is used only for the calculation/math once the user has cleared the requirements of the form.

If someone could provide a clear and concise example, it would much appreciated.  I've tried to find a suitable example via google searching, however nothing seemed to fit.  Also I'm trying to avoid using a validator plugin, which seemed to be the go to answer when googling the question. 
 I have my reasons and will be more than happy to explain if needed.

Thank-you, 
Charles

Comment: What are your reasons? The jquery.validation plugin is the easiest and best way to do form validation.

Comment: playing devil's advocate, plugin is one extra file that has to be loaded

Comment: as @Alastair Pitts mentioned you should go or the plugin than writing a code of your own, why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @yitwail - well, that depends on how you handle js files. Can you explain how it is different than writing your own code?

Comment: @Falcon, your own code *could* be an external JS file that has to be loaded, in which case there's no difference. But if the code is in <head> or <body> of the web page, there's one less request to the server to fetch a JS file.

Comment: Alstari Pitts presented you with the anwser. jQuery.validation plugin + CSS styling and you are a winner

Comment: @yitwail - I'm afraid putting code in <head> or <body> isn't a good approach!!

Answer (score 1):

if you take away the aspect of your question, validation is fairly basic. All jquery would be used for is to make selecting specific dom elements easier

```
$(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    return checkFormIsValid();
  });
  $('#field1').keyup(function() {
    checkField(this.id);
  });
  $('#field2').keyup(function() {
    checkField(this.id);
  });
});

function checkFormIsValid()
{
  return checkField('field1') && checkField('field2');
}

function checkField(fieldId) 
{
  var val = $('#'+fieldId).val();
  // validation logic
  if(isValid) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert(fieldId+ ' is not valid');
    return false;
  }
}
```

This basic validation will be triggered on each field, as well as when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

As **Ben Rowe**  suggest you can use that code, but in checkField(fieldId)  function you have to validate that input data should be integer only in that case you can use these codes to vaildate that.

[**Regex to validet input data**](http://ntt.cc/2008/05/10/over-10-useful-javascript-regular-expression-functions-to-improve-your-web-applications-efficiency.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var isEmail_re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
function isEmail(s) {
    return String(s).search(isEmail_re) != -1;
}

function isBlank(s) {
    if (!s || s.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    // checks for a non-white space character 
    // which I think [citation needed] is faster 
    // than removing all the whitespace and checking 
    // against an empty string
    return !/[^\s]+/.test(s);
}


function SendContactForm() {
    var isFormValid = true; 

    var isEmailOk = isEmail($('#cemail').val());
    if (isEmailOk == false) {
        $('#emEmail').css('color', 'red');
        isFormValid = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#emEmail').css('color', 'black');
    }

    var isNameOk = isBlank($('#cname').val());
    if (isNameOk) {
        $('#emName').css('color', 'red');
        isFormValid = false;
        //alert('!');
    }
    else {
        $('#emName').css('color', 'black');
    }

    var isSubjectOk = isBlank($('#csubject').val());
    if (isSubjectOk) {
        $('#emSubject').css('color', 'red');
        isFormValid = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#emSubject').css('color', 'black');
    }

    var isMesageOk = isBlank($('#cmessage').val());
    if (isMesageOk) {
        $('#emMessage').css('color', 'red');
        isFormValid = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#emMessage').css('color', 'black');
    }

    if (isFormValid) {


        $('#contactFormFields').hide("explode", 1000);


        $.post("/Home/SendContactForm", { email: $('#cemail').val(),
            name: $('#cname').val(),
            subject: $('#csubject').val(),
            message: $('#cmessage').val()
        },
                 function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        // alert(data);
                        }
         });
    }
}




 <div id="contactFormFields">

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150px;">
                                E-Mail
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="cemail" type="text" value="E-mail" name="email" size="25" class="required email" /><em id="emEmail">*</em>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150px;">
                                Name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" maxlength="100" /><em id="emName">*</em>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150px;">
                                Subject
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="csubject" name="subject" size="25" class="required" maxlength="200" /><em id="emSubject">*</em>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150px; vertical-align: top;">
                                Message
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea id="cmessage" maxlength="1000" name="comment" cols="27" rows="10" class="required"></textarea><em id="emMessage">*</em>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 150px;">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="input-btn" onclick="SendContactForm();" style=" width:100px; color: Black;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your looking for a plug in to validate form fields?

you can give this a try: http://www.vanadiumjs.com/
just add its js file and your ready.

adding a required validation is as simple as adding css like this

```
 <input class=":required" type="text">
```

to add an integer validation

```
<input class=":integer" type="text">
```

and so on. just follow the link for more info.